# What is the simplest way to make ip link add/addr commands exist after a reboot?

Tags: networking, 20.04, interface, persistence

after each restart of my server (ubuntu server 20.04) i have to give these commands:

```
sudo ip link add macvlan0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.200/29 dev macvlan0
sudo ip link set macvlan0 up
```

Unfortunately doing some research I discovered that it is not enough to modify netplan and i would like to ask if anyone knows a simple method to get the macvlan0 interface working after reboot. Sorry my poor english, i hope you can understand my question.

Comment: You've tagged `persistence`, so is this a *live* system (not a conventional installed system) booted from thumb-drive (etc) with persistence enabled?

Comment: Look at `examples.netplan.io`, and set up your configuration in netplan.

Comment: @guiverc No, maybe I made a mistake in choosing the tag, it's a normal installation. What I try is to avoid giving these commands every time the server is restarted

Comment: @waltinator unfortunately at the moment netplan does not support macvlan interfaces: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1664847